# Is it possible to have a horizontal list and append to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I hope this makes sense, as I don't really know how to explain it other than -- I'm appending items to a separate list as shown below.

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
list3=[]
.
.
.
list12=[]
```

There are 12 in total, so my question is-- is it possible to do something like this instead:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6,
... list12 = []
```

to only use two lines instead of 12 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a list of empty lists, and use the index to select:

```
my_lists = [[] for _ in range(12)]
my_lists[1]
# []
```

Comment: @sharpie_pen and don't forget that the index will be 0-11, not 1-12.